# Developing Andriod application to list videos and play them on selction

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments, video

I am new to Android development (barely a month and half) , we have a requirement of developing an application which would list out you tube videos and allow user to play them , to begin with i was asked to list out any ten random videos (size would increase in future) with an option for the user to choose and play them. I have seen a few posts which asked me to use the YOUTUBE api , few of which suggested video view however as i am new to this side of coding i was not able to .Can somebody please help me with the code or possible options which would help me to complete my application .
Thank you in advance for your time and support.
Vibhav

Comment: StackOverflow is about solving specified problems, not to provide code..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Youtube API would be best for this. I suggestion you to load thumbnails of the videos in the RecyclerView and then play when clicked.

For reference, you can have a look into this [URL](https://androidtutorialmagic.wordpress.com/my-mini-project/multiple-youtube-video-in-recyclerviewlistview-in-android/).

Comment: Thank you Sanjog, i am new to Android and will surely look into it .

Comment: Everyone has started with the tag "New". All th very best!

Comment: Thank you Sanjog for the link, definitely helped.